# DNS Server Fails to Install on Windows Standard 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, dns-server

When I add the DNS Role in Windows Standard 2008, it will run through the install process and then fail. It's a windows 64-bit standalone box.

Any common pitfalls?

**Update**

I logged in as the Administrator and it worked. The account I was using before was part of the Administrators group... not sure why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like User Access Control (UAC). Before doing any install, right-click and "Run as administrator".  A user in the administrators group is different than the primary administrator and needs extra approval to run administrative tasks and installs.

Comment: That's probably what it was...